# Why does my computer crash when I use 2 memory sticks?

Tags: memory, crash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing two RAM sticks causes problems; using only one of them doesn't?](https://superuser.com/questions/331067/installing-two-ram-sticks-causes-problems-using-only-one-of-them-doesnt)

Motherboard: P7N SLI Platinum
Memory sticks: 2x DDR2 PC2 6400

It works fine with one stick in, but if I but both in I get a BSOD after a random amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

Your motherboard I would say is defective. Try and run [Memtest86](http://www.memtest.org/) with both sticks in and see if you get any errors, then run it with just a single stick. If you have access to another stick of RAM (maybe a friend?), try running it with the first and the loaner stick. It may be that your second stick of ram is defective and not your motherboard.

Comment: What's the USB got to do with the DDR2 memory sticks?

Comment: wow, completely missed that part... I will pull my answer...

Answer (score 0):

It could be a motherboard problem or a RAM problem. It could also be a bug with the BIOS firmware.

In addition to trying out [brandon927](https://superuser.com/questions/223462/why-does-my-computer-crash-when-i-use-2-memory-sticks/223464#223464)'s suggestions, you could also try flashing a newer version of the BIOS firmware if there is one available. Here's a list of BIOS updates available for [P7N SLI Platinum](http://www.msi.com/index.php?func=downloaddetail&type=bios&maincat_no=1&prod_no=1373).